# Saving a ggplot2 plot: how to save processing time when using ggsave

Tags: r, plot, time, ggplot2

I have code creating two different plots, then using arrangeGrob from the gridExtra package to put those two plots into one and then using the ggsave function to store them to my disk by using the following chunk of code:

```
 ggsave(filename = paste0("plot-lin-fit", no1, "attribute-",no2, "type-", var.type, ".png"),
     plot = p3,
     path = "./lin fit plots/", width = 38, height = 16.92, units = "cm")
```

When I run this as part of a function to create the two plots ten times, the function takes 26 seconds to create the two plots, put them in one plotting window and to store them with ggsave to my disk. When I run the function without the ggsave part of code, it takes only 16 seconds. So by leaving out ggsave the time gets reduced significantly. Since I want to this for a lot of dataframes, not only 10 times but rather 3600 times, I need to reduce time if possible.

How can reduce time plotting those functions? Any help is appreciated, as I am a newby.

Comment: It's difficult to make suggestions without having an idea of what you're trying to plot.  Can you produce an example plot with reproducible code?

Comment: ggplot2 is slow, I don't think there is much you can do about it. Note that much of the work to build the plot is done at the stage where it is printed/saved; it can be a bit misleading.

Comment: maybe reducing plot size could help. Do you really need a 38x17 cm png ?